# Error when trying to use a input value as the name of the data frame that I downloaded

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

I'm trying to make a simple financial calculator that is capable of converting currencies as well. I couldn't go on without quantmod, to download new information. But when I try to apply its functions in shiny, there's some problem that I couldn't make out.

```r
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("curr", "Currency"),
    actionButton("go", "1 dollar equals to:")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("res")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  result <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    getSymbols(input$curr)
    result$data <- data.frame(`input$curr`)
    wanted <- result$data[nrow(result$data), ncol(result$data)]
   })


  output$res <- renderText({
    paste(wanted)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I tried to do the same in other script, without the inputs of shiny, it worked pretty well.
When I used BRL=X as the input$curr, it should work as in the script shown below.

```r
getSymbols("BRL=X")

data <- data.frame(`BRL=X`)

data[nrow(data),ncol(data)]
```

But the error message that appear says that object "input$curr" was not found.

Comment: remove the backticks around input$curr?

Comment: I'd suggest you go with the more *functional* method, with `data <- getSymbols("BRL-X", auto.assign=FALSE)`.